# syntax inconsistency when declaring a Function Type

Tags: haskell

If i'm creating a function, let's take the simplest example:

```
add x y = x + y
```

if i want to add a Function Type declaration before, for clarity sake

```
add :: (Int, Int) -> Int
add x y = x + y
```

I get a compile error:
"Couldn't match expected type ‘Int’ with actual type ‘(Int, Int) -> (Int, Int)’".
"The equation(s) for ‘add’ have two arguments, but its type ‘(Int, Int) -> Int’ has only one"

but it compiles flawlessly if i correct it to

```
add :: (Int, Int) -> Int
add (x, y) = x + y
```

coming from other languages, i actually think it's clearer to use the second form with parenthesis, but in my opinion, both ways should work

1 - what is the reason for not working the first way?
2 - i find the error messages completely confusing so, maybe, the error happens for another reason i don't understand

Comment: The second one works on a 2-tuple. In Haskell every function takes *one* parameter. A function like `add` that seems to take two parameters, will actually construct a new function if you write `add 2`, a function that will take a parameter and add two to that parameter.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, not sure i understand completely the concept of `add x y = x + y` constructing a 2 functions... but i'm sure it will come with time

Comment: i understand the tuple explanation and the fact that in that case, it's not actual 2 arguments but a Tuple as a single argument

Comment: It's worth looking at the type of `add x y = x + y`, which is `Int -> Int -> Int`.  That means something different from `(Int, Int) -> Int`

Comment: i think i'm starting to get it, it's basically a curried function in that case... it's just a totally different paradygm...

Comment: @AndréAlçadaPadez: well strictly speaking a language like Java could also implement currying, such that one can call `add2(x)` and thus get a function and then call that, so `add2(x)(y)` could result in summing it up. In fact in Python that is even easy to implement. Likely one of the main reasons it is not implemented is that it makes it unclear when the function will run, and since functions in imperative language often have side-effects, the order of calling functions matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what is the reason for not working the first way?

In the first expression your type says it takes a 2-tuple as single parameter, and it returns the sum of the two items. But in the "body" of the function, you specify `add x y = x + y` hence you construct a function that takes a parameter `x` that will return a function that will take a parameter `y` which maps to `x + y`.

In Haskell *all* functions take *one* parameter. Indeed, your `add` function takes one parameter `x`. It is short for:

```
add x = \y -> x + y
```

It thus returns a function that will take a parameter `y` and then maps `y` to `x + y`. If you thus construct a function `f = add 2`, then `f` will take the parameter `y`, and map this on `2 + y`.

The arrow is a right-associative operator. This means that `Int -> Int -> Int` is short for `Int -> (Int -> Int)`, it thus is a function that maps an `Int` to another function.

You can see the syntax of languages like Java where they call `f (x, y)` basically as calling the function `f` with one object: a 2-tuple with `x` and `y` as its two elements.

Comment: I get it now. Is there any efficiency difference between the two ways?

Comment: @AndréAlçadaPadez: behind the curtains functional languages will make use of *push/enter* or *eval/apply* method, so currying isn't done at the implementation, it is mainly used as what the language offers, and the compiler thus aims to optimize this: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/eval-apply.pdf

Comment: Generally `Int -> Int -> Int` avoids allocating the tuples and is what the language is optimized for.